# Reading a file from the clipboard with the Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, clipboard

I am trying to read a file from the clipboard using the Clipboard API according to the manual , but my browser throws the error.

I am trying to read a file from the clipboard using the Clipboard API in this way:

```
const clipboard = await window.navigator.clipboard.read();
console.debug(clipboard);
```

The browser throws an error when executing this code:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: No valid data on clipboard.
```

Can you tell me how to make sure that this error does not occur and it is possible to receive files from the clipboard?

Comment: Ok, I catch errors via try/catch, but my clipboard contains copied image and browser throws error

Answer (score 0):

You should catch errors if the clipboard is empty...

```
try {
  const clipboard = await navigator.clipboard.read();
  console.debug(clipboard);
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error reading clipboard:', error);
}
```

Note not all browsers actually support this feature as of now, so there's that as well permissions; there's a bit to the APIs capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to ensure that this error does not occur and its possible to receive files from the clipboard you can use `?` operator. To check the availability of a parameter. This is also known as the Optional Chaining Operator.**

Refer to the below code for usage :

```js
  const clipboard = navigator?.clipboard?.read();
  console.log(clipboard);
```